# How to support Pan/Zoom with Gmap in WebBrowser?

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-maps, browser

For I have a javascript version GMap.html, I can successfully display it in the WP7 WebBrowser, but I cannot make it pan or zoom in; is there a way to disable the default gesture    behavior(such as fix the position the map's div; if I slide up, the map pans to north, when I double touch, it zooms) to allow the GMaps panning or zooming?

Here attached a very simple sample, when opening the emulator, you can see the map is displayed, but when we want slide up/down to pan north or south, it works like panning the web browser up or down.

http://hotfile.com/dl/135072503/ec55e86/PhoneApp1.7z.html

Thanks,

Comment: Is this about a local copy of some map or about the real thing (http://maps.google.com/)? Can you provide a URL for testing?

Comment: I attached a simple sample, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to hook the manipulation events from the Border that surrounds the ContentPresenter in the visual tree for the WebBrowser control to intercept them before they get to the PanZoomContainer, which would allow you to do whatever you need to with the content.

Colin Eberhardt has a great post about it on his [blog](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/suppressing-zoom-and-scroll-interactions-in-the-windows-phone-7-browser-control/) where he basically disabled the standard manipulation events for doing HTML5 apps on Windows Phone, but the concept is still the same.